# Make more room for lables in ggplot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, geom-text

Is there a way to have this plot squeezed a little so labels of extreme cases (A and G) have could show up completely.
[image]

code:

```
x <- LETTERS[1:11]
y <- c(9, 4, 6, 8, 5, 7, -9, -4, -6, -8, -5)
z <- seq(-1, 1, by = 0.2)

dat <- data.frame(x, y, z) |> 
  mutate(just_text = ifelse(z > 0, 1, -0.2))

dat %>%
  ggplot(aes(fct_reorder(x, y, .desc = T), y)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = paste0(abs(y), " ", "abcdef"), 
        hjust = just_text)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(
  axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8, 
                             lineheight = 1, 
                             margin = margin(r = 1, unit = "cm")))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Alternatively, you can add `coord_cartesian(clip = "off")` so that text can extend beyond the plot area. You might need to also expand margins on the side in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `expand` -

```
library(ggplot2)

dat %>%
  ggplot(aes(fct_reorder(x, y, .desc = T), y)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = paste0(abs(y), " ", "abcdef"), 
        hjust = just_text)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8, 
                               lineheight = 1)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(add = c(5, 5)))
```

[image]

In this case, I have expanded the axis by 5 units each in both the direction. You may adjust it according to your requirement.

Comment: For aesthetics adjustments, this is the better answer :)

Comment: Thanks Ronak. Is it possible to extend the axis tick labels as well? For instance, change the `G` value to -12 and run the code again. Then you could see axis tick labels don't extended to the expansion used for whole graph. I asekd another question for this problem [link ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77857138/how-to-change-axis-tick-labels-when-use-expansion-term-in-scale-y-continuous). Thank again.

Answer (score 0):

I would just extend the y-axis with `ylim()`—you're not cutting off any data points, so just adjust accordingly:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
x <- LETTERS[1:11]
y <- c(9, 4, 6, 8, 5, 7, -9, -4, -6, -8, -5)
z <- seq(-1, 1, by = 0.2)

dat <- data.frame(x, y, z) |> 
  mutate(just_text = dplyr::if_else(z > 0, 1, -0.2)) |>
  ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x, y, .desc = T), y) +
  ggplot2::geom_col() +
  ggplot2::geom_text(
    ggplot2::aes(
      label = paste0(abs(y), " ", "abcdef"), 
      hjust = just_text
    )
  ) +
  ggplot2::ylim(c(-15, 15)) +
  ggplot2::coord_flip() +
  ggplot2::theme(
    axis.text.y = element_text(
      size = 8, 
      lineheight = 1, 
      margin = margin(r = 1, unit = "cm"))
    )
```