# How to change axis tick labels when use expansion term in scale_y_continuous

Tags: r, ggplot2

How could I manipulate axis labels so both ends of axis have tick labels (I don't want axis to extend beyond end labels). I show below what would be my desired output.

Also, it would be great to functionalize labels argument in scale_y_continuous so they automatically do that for any variable in a dataset (axis tick labels at both end when using expansion)

[image]

code:

```
x <- LETTERS[1:11]
y <- c(9, 4, 6, 8, 5, 7, -12, -4, -6, -8, -5)
z <- seq(-1, 1, by = 0.2)

dat <- data.frame(x, y, z) |> 
  mutate(just_text = ifelse(z > 0, 1, -0.2))

dat %>%
  ggplot(aes(fct_reorder(x, y, .desc = T), y)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(abs(y), " ", "abcdef"), hjust = just_text)) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = function(x) paste0(abs(x), "%"),
    #limits = c(-15,15),
    expand = expansion(add = c(5, 5))
  ) +
  theme(
        axis.ticks.y.left = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_line(color = "black"))
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a possible answer for your first question but unfortunately I didn't manage to functionalise it, at least not for setting the axis limits. I have only changed the `coord_flip()` and  `scale_y_continuous` functions :

```
coord_flip(ylim = c(ceiling(min(dat$y)/5)*5-5, ceiling(max(dat$y)/5)*5+5)) +
scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = function(x) seq(ceiling(min(x)/5)*5, ceiling(max(x)/5)*5, by = 5),
    labels = function(x) paste0(abs(x), "%"),
    minor_breaks = NULL,
    expand = c(0,0)
  ) +
```

By setting the `ylim` inside `coord_flip` we can "zoom" on only the part of the axis we want, but that means setting `expand` to 0. I tried to functionalise the `coord_flip` but i returned an error. You might be able to find a fix though.